Corrupted Xubuntu 24.04 - grub rescue error after Update and Upgrade (Dual Boot) MBR
I am a fairly new user to Xubuntu. I had it installed a few days ago as a dual boot beside my windows 10.
I installed it inside of a extended portion of my disk (1TB WD - MBR). It originally had 5 drives: C:, D: (Audio), E: (Files), F: (Video) and G: (Games). Out of these 5, only 3 were marked as part of the extended drive which I can't remember exactly. The only thing I remember is inside of Windows 10 Disk Partition tool, the last 3 were inside of a green/blue box marked as extended partition. It had some free space of around 105GB and I decided to install Xubuntu in it. I had to runsudo grub-install /dev/sda to install grub because it was not showing up.
I completed the installation from a bootable live pendrive and was using it without any issues up until last night. I ran the sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update and then shut down the laptop using Shut down option in xubuntu menu.
Today when I tried to start my laptop it showed me a black screen with GRUB error. It was saying: Error: no such partition. Entering grub rescue... grub rescue>
I still had the live bootable pendrive so I am currently inside of a live boot. I tried to fix the partition using ChatGPT's help. But when I ran the command sudo fdisk -l it didn't show my xubuntu partition which was /dev/sda8 and /dev/sda9 (swap partition).
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10JPVX-75J
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf8fe467f

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048    1026047    1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          1026048  275777535  274751488   131G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        275777536  695007840  419230305 199.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4        695009278 1953521071 1258511794 600.1G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        900012704 1217043824  317031121 151.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       5512009135 9806976429 4294967295     2T ff BBT

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 6 does not start on physical sector boundary.

In panic, I asked search online but couldn't find any solutions. I turned to chatGPT and with it's instruction I installed TestDisk. After I ran it from terminal it showed:
The harddisk (1000 GB/931GiB) seems too small! (<1297GB/1208GiB) 

Check the harddisk size: HD jumper settings, BIOS detection

The following partition can't be recovered:

Partition: HPFS - NTFS
Start: 121601 57 56
End: 167764 51 46
Size in sectors: 580958208

and after using Quick Search it showed the following ones after a long time of scanning:
TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>D HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33    63 221 30    1024000 [System Reserved]
 D HPFS - NTFS             63 221 31 17166  91 13  274751488
 D HPFS - NTFS          17166  91 14 43262  83 21  419231744 [Files]
 D Linux                43262  83 22 54204  29 33  175779840
 D Linux Swap           54204  62  3 56023   7 48   29218816
 D HPFS - NTFS          56023  50 60 75757 120 60  317031121 [Audio]
 D HPFS - NTFS          75757 121 61 101865 207 22  419430400 [Video]
 D HPFS - NTFS          85438  64  3 121601  57 56  580958208

I tried accessing the files using p to list files I could see most drives except for Linux and the last one D HPFS - NTFS          85438  64  3 121601  57 56  580958208. For these two instead of listing the files it showed Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.
By process of elimination I can guess the last one is the G: Games drive. I tried the following combination of selecting drive types to recover but I kept getting Bad structure warning.
TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 P HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33    63 221 30    1024000 [System Reserved]
 P HPFS - NTFS             63 221 31 17166  91 13  274751488
>L HPFS - NTFS          17166  91 14 43262  83 21  419231744 [Files]
 P Linux                43262  83 22 54204  29 33  175779840
 L Linux Swap           54204  62  3 56023   7 48   29218816
 L HPFS - NTFS          56023  50 60 75757 120 60  317031121 [Audio]
 L HPFS - NTFS          75757 121 61 101865 207 22  419430400 [Video]
 D HPFS - NTFS          85438  64  3 121601  57 56  580958208


Structure: Bad. Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
*=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
     Enter: to continue
NTFS, blocksize=4096, 214 GB / 199 GiB

I tried many times but it won't let me select the E=Extended option for any of the drives. I didn't get the warning if I selected them in this way: (Excluding the Files drive)
Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 P HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33    63 221 30    1024000 [System Reserved]
 P HPFS - NTFS             63 221 31 17166  91 13  274751488
 D HPFS - NTFS          17166  91 14 43262  83 21  419231744 [Files]
 P Linux                43262  83 22 54204  29 33  175779840
 L Linux Swap           54204  62  3 56023   7 48   29218816
 L HPFS - NTFS          56023  50 60 75757 120 60  317031121 [Audio]
 L HPFS - NTFS          75757 121 61 101865 207 22  419430400 [Video]
>D HPFS - NTFS          85438  64  3 121601  57 56  580958208

But I am scared to continue fearing I will mess something more. I don't want to lose data in Games drive. I can sacrifice Linux and Linux Swap if needed be. I didn't know a simple update and upgrade would destroy my files like this. Please I need urgent help!

use HBCD_PE_64 there is a program called EaseUS Partition Master this will recover your partition. this program helped me to restore my partition.

Thanks for the comment but I am not really how to proceed from here. I am still inside of a Xubuntu 24.04 live boot from a pendrive

use Ventoy from Ubuntu to make the ventoy disk from your pendrive, add Xubuntu and HBCD_PE_64 ISO files to the ventoy disk, and boot with any one from them https://itsfoss.com/use-ventoy/

I am not sure I can do that right now. I am only able to access this because of the live boot I have in this pendrive (which unfortunately I have only one). I don't have any other means right now to do this.

use this method https://askubuntu.com/questions/1476911/create-recovery-partition-to-install-backup-restore-and-repair-multi-ubuntu-v

Well after trying for 2 days, I have come to a conclusion that somehow my partitions were messed up. I still do not know how. I backed up whatever data I could using testdisk and now starting over. My old setup was in MBR and now converting it to UEFI. I tried recovering some data using photorec but it was unable to see the lost partitions.
Anyway thank you for your help.
